# Failed to install node-inspector on Sierra

Tags: node.js, npm-install

when I install node-inspector with 'npm install -g node-inspector' via node v7.3.0  npm 4.0.5, I got the errors below. Then I try to solve my problem with 'node install -g node-pre-gyp' as the errors indicate, but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.
    [image: error_1]
    [image: error_2]
    [image: error_3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/940) on the `node-inspector` project about this.

For a very similar experience, you can now use the built in Node.js inspector by adding the `--inspect` flag when you start your app. For example:

```
node --inspect myapp.js
```

This will then give you a Chrome dev tools console to debug your code in, in a similar way to `node-inspector`.